# curl file transfer error PHP

Tags: php, curl, file-transfer

I can transfer HD videos from youtube successfully. Because youtube gives me high speed to download HD video. But SD or HQ videos i cannot transfer to my server because youtube gives low speed for SD or HQ videos. When I want to transfer SD or HQ videos I get an 
**'504 Gateway Time-out 

The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.'** 
If youtube give me high speed to transfer video i dont get this error. How can I fix it? My code is:

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$url = base64_decode($url);
$file = uniqid();
$file2 = $file;
$extension = $_POST['extension'];
$extension = base64_decode($extension);
set_time_limit(0);
$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . "/downloads/$file.$extension", 'w+');
    $ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch); // get curl response
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Double down on your CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and see what that does for you

Comment: Do you need your own code for this? If not, you can invoke an external tool like `youtube.dl` using the `system()` command. Or you can check out the tools python code to see how it handles different issues.

Comment: Atle how can I do it? Please tell me...